# python's os.path.expanduser('~') inconsistent windows behaviour

Tags: python, environment-variables

```
from os.path import expanduser
print expanduser('~')
```

in a "dos" box command line:

```
c:c:\users\myuser     <-- incorrect
```

in a pythonwin session:

```
c:\users\myuser       <-- correct
```

it's the same python 2.7.8 interpreter for both of the interpreters.
it probably depends if i run in from the console.

if I ran a script from the command line, it will be wrong.  same script running from pythonwin shows the correct version.

what's going on?  (i'm on windows7)

```
C:\> echo %HOMEDRIVE%
C:

C:\> echo %HOMEPATH%
\Users\myuser

C:\> echo %HOME%
C:C:\Users\myuser          <--  aha!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening here is Python is expanding `~` to one of the following, with this precedence:

- `%HOME%`
- `%USERPROFILE%`
- `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`

So, on your machine, I suspect `HOMEPATH` is defined `c:\users\myuser` instead of the correct `\users\myuser`. `HOMEDRIVE` is probably correctly set to `c:`

In your pythonwin it is probably defining `HOME` or `USERPROFILE` properly.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

> On Windows, HOME and USERPROFILE will be used if set, otherwise a combination of HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE will be used. An initial ~user is handled by stripping the last directory component from the created user path derived above.

Comment: PS Not part of the answer, but I believe some of these environment vars are set by network admin, so if you cannot correct them yourself, I suggest asking that question on superuser, see for example: http://superuser.com/questions/255776/overriding-homedrive-and-homepath-as-a-windows-7-user

Comment: Yes, not exacly, @jonahGraham:   on my machine the problem was the %home% variable.   thanks.

Comment: Great, I am glad I was of assistance. Did you find out what set home to the incorrect value?

Comment: no, i don't know. i just know that HOME doesn't come from windows natives, so it' probably one of the cross-platform programs i have here.  It was set to some   C:C:\Users\myuser